# to-infinitive or present participle?

Tags: meaning, present-participles, to-infinitive

The sentence I am stuck with:

> The specimen **to be tested** is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes.

I paraphrase it in my mind:

> The specimen **which will be tested** is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes.

After reducing the sentence I paraphrased:

> The specimen **tested** is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes.

To me, *to be* is redundant in *The specimen to be tested is...*

If the sentence is correct, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The "passive infinitive" (such as *to be tested*) usually has an implication of intention, especially when it follows a form of *to be*.

So *The specimen is to be tested.* means more than *The specimen is tested*: it means that there is an intention of testing it.

The same is true in a relative clause:

> *The specimen which is to be tested* means something different from *the specimen which is tested*.

and in a reduced relative clause:

> *The specimen to be tested* is different from *The specimen tested*.

In fact, in this last case, there is even more difference, because the verb omitted in the Whiz-deletion could be *is* or *was*. In the absence of any overriding context, *the specimen tested* will be interpreted as *the specimen which was tested*.

So *the specimen to be tested* means "the specimen which somebody intends/intended to test", while *the specimen tested* usually means "the specimen which was/has been tested".

Comment: **"..., the specimen tested will be interpreted as the specimen which was tested."** Can we? Souldn't we say "the specimen having been tested" to emphasize that it tested before?

Comment: While you could in principle use _having been tested_ in that way, I don't think anybody would, because _tested_ already means "which was tested". So if you wrote "the specimen having been tested" I would probably not recognise it as a noun phrase with reduced relative clause (like "the specimen tested") but would parse it as an absolute clause, like "the show having finished, we left the theatre".

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that "The specimen which will be tested is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes." is not suitable in this context, because you are talking about an action that is presently taking place.

As for the other two, I am unsure of what the context is for which you need this, so I will explain both. 
If you are writing up a scientific experiment method, let's say, it would be better to use "The specimen to be tested is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes."
For "The specimen tested is injected into an environmental chamber through which a constant flow of air passes", you can use this in the same situation, however it also makes it sound a little like the action took place in the past, or that someone is commentating on the action.